# I'm using KeyValueObjectMapping developed by dchohfi. But facing issue in mapping JSON object array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, key-value-observing, nskeyvaluecoding

[JSON Model Library](https://github.com/dchohfi/KeyValueObjectMapping)

I have a Json object & respective models -

```
{
"type": "flight",
"senderid": "101",
"message": 
{
    "origin": "Bangalore",
    "destination": "Paris",
    "start_date": "21-04-2017",
    "end_date": "27-04-2017",
    "price": "300",
    "currency": "$",
    "fare_rules": "This is the fare rules text.",
    "refundable": "true",
    "check_in_baggage": "30 kg",
    "legs": [
        {
            "index": "1",
            "airline_id": "2003",
            "flight_number": "TK 721 T",
            "name": "Turkish Airline",
            "logo": "http://turkish.com/logo.png",
            "origin": "Bangalore",
            "destination": "Chennai",
            "start_date": "21-04-2017",
            "end_date": "21-04-2017",
            "start_time": "06.20 pm",
            "end_time": "8.15 pm",
            "journey_time": "2h 30m",
            "is_next": "true",
            "layover": "3 hours"
        },
        {
            "index": "2",
            "airline_id": "4003",
            "flight_number": "JT 021",
            "name": "Jet Airways",
            "logo": "http://jetairways.com/logo.png",
            "origin": "Chennai",
            "destination": "Paris",
            "start_date": "21-04-2017",
            "end_date": "21-04-2017",
            "start_time": "11.20 pm",
            "end_time": "2.15 am",
            "journey_time": "3h 10m",
            "is_next": "false",
            "layover": ""
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Mapping code -

```
DCParserConfiguration *config = [DCParserConfiguration configuration];

DCArrayMapping *mapper = [DCArrayMapping mapperForClassElements:[TRChatFlightLegModel class] forAttribute:@"legs" onClass:[TRChatFlightMessageModel class]];

[config addArrayMapper:mapper];

DCKeyValueObjectMapping *parser = [DCKeyValueObjectMapping mapperForClass:[TRChatTypeFlightsModel class] andConfiguration:config];

TRChatTypeFlightsModel *chatTextModel = [parser parseDictionary:message.data.message];
```

And my model classes looks like this:

```
@interface TRChatTypeFlightsModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger senderid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TRChatFlightMessageModel *message;

@end

@interface TRChatFlightMessageModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *origin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *destination;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *start_date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *end_date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *fare_rules;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *flight_legs;

@interface TRChatFlightLegModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *airline_id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *is_next;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *layover;

@end
```

I'm getting value for **chatTextModel.message.origin** but getting `nil` for **chatTextModel.message.flight_legs**. Any suggestions?

Comment: what actually you want to parse the data from above JSON ?

Comment: @vaibhav , I want to parse everything from above data and I am getting all the values except **legs** from the json.

Comment: okay, check my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Model class object name "**flight_legs**" into "**legs**". Because in here
*JSON Model Library* does mapping

> **json key path <----> object key path**.

Hence change

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *flight_legs;
```

to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *legs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here are the dict inside dict while `legs` is a dict which contains array of two elements.

You can fetch `JSON` data as simple as:

```
// returned string contaning JSON data
NSData *data = [returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// json can be NSDictionary *json
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

// parsing data from main dict (JSON data)
NSDictionary *innerDict1 = [json valueForKey:@"message"];

// now parsing data from message dict
NSDictionary *innerDict2 = [innerDict1 valueForKey:@"legs"];

// parsing node of legs dict, can pass any key inside legs
NSLog(@"values: %@", [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"airline_id"]);

// getting values inside mutable array 
array1 = [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"index"];    
array2 = [innerDict2 valueForKey:@"airline_id"];
```